# Android - push updates/news to user

Tags: android, push-notification

If we assume the user has *not* started your app, how do you send/push news/updates?

For instance, imagine the user installed "shops-in-your-area" app and set some option to inform the user when new shops launch... But the user forgets to run the app. How do you auto-launch and/or auto-check for news to show them inside Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you start by looking into Google Cloud Messaging. You might have seen it referred to before as 'GCM'. http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

This should provide all the functionality you require.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Accepted as answer :)